# Comparision of file contents with an integer variable yields false for the following code

Tags: python

I have created my file as follows

```
f= open('filename','w')
for i in range(1,some_size):
        f.write("%d\r\n"%i)
        if (f.tell()<some_size):
            continue
        else:
            break

def check_file(file_path)
    value = 0
    for line in open(file_path, "rb"):
        print value == int(line)
        value += 1
check_file(file1)
```

why am I printing `False` in here?? when i checked the contents and the type both were doing good.

p.s.:- I am a beginner in python.

Comment: You should flush and/or close your first file somewhere. What is the `tell` supposed to do? Why do you write in text mode and read in binary mode? You should strip trailing `\r\n` from your lines while reading before passing them to `int()`.

Comment: i am doing it on purpose as i need the file to be of a particular size and with new lines.

Comment: Thank you. Let's say `some_size` equals 10, should the file be `1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4` (size 10, but truncated) or `1\r\n\2\r\n3\r\n` (size 9, not truncated) or `1\r\n\2\r\n3\r\n4\r\n` (size 12, not truncated)?

Comment: that would be 1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4 @Hyperboreus

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You are starting from '1' when you write the file, but from '0' when you read it:

Write: `i in range(1,...)`

Read: `value = 0`

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a lot of issues in your code. Maybe this snippet can point you in the right direction:

```
def makeFile(fname, size):
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
        for i in range(1, size):
            f.write("{}\r\n".format(i))

def checkFile(fname):
    value = 1
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            print (value == int(line.strip()))
            value += 1

makeFile('out', 12)
checkFile('out')
```

---

EDIT: If you want to limit the file size even if truncating, the `makeFile` could look like this:

```
def makeFile(fname, size):
    with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
        i = 0
        while True:
            i += 1
            data = '{}\r\n'.format(i).encode('utf-8')
            if len(data) > size: data = data[:size]
            if not data: break
            size -= len(data)
            f.write(data)
```